# Executing a function every second

Tags: rust

```
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut lastsec = Instant::now();

    loop {
        if Instant::now() - lastsec >= Duration::from_secs(1) {
            dostuff();
            lastsec = Instant::now();
        }
    }
}

fn dostuff() {
    println!("Performing action...");
}
```

This Rust code should execute the `dostuff()` function every second.
However it doesn't execute it at all. The reason i am not using sleep is because i need to do other stuff inside this loop faster than once a second.

```
use std::time::{Instant, Duration};

fn main() {
    let mut lastsec = Instant::now();

    loop {
        if Instant::now() - lastsec >= Duration::from_secs(1) {
            dostuff();
        }
    }
}

fn dostuff() {
    println!("Performing action...");
}
```

This slightly changed version where i removed the reassignment `lastsec = Instant::now();` works as expected. It waits a second then starts calling `dostuff()` every loop iteration.

Comment: The first code snippet works for me. I.e. it runs every second. `rustc 1.70.0 (90c541806 2023-05-31)` / `Linux workstation 6.4.1-arch2-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue, 04 Jul 2023 08:39:40 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: This spins really, **really** hard. You probably want to [sleep](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) rather than chewing up an entire core checking the time.

Comment: This does work, but I would change it to use `elapsed`, increment `lastsec` instead of reassigning it, and sleep for some small amount of time to simulate doing substantial work. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da1571929e0fbe015506c2021384f6ee

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The code you provided does work.

Comment: If you are not afraid of adding an async runtime to your code, I suggest taking a look at [`tokio::time::interval()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.interval.html).

Comment: *"because I need to do other stuff inside this loop faster than once a second."* - I think your error lies in this "other stuff" you don't actually show. The code you show here works as intended.

Comment: @Finomnis it didn't, i updated rust and it works now

Comment: In that case I vote to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constantly querying the elapsed amount of time, try *sleeping* at the end of each loop instance. Rewrite your loop using [`sleep`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.sleep.html) from `std::thread`:

> **Function std::thread::sleep**
>
> Puts the current thread to sleep for at least the specified amount of time.

Example:

```rust
use std::thread::sleep;
use std::time::Duration;

loop {
    dostuff();

    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
}
```

Whilst this does not guarantee each call to `dostuff` to be *exactly* one second apart, it does wait one second between the return from and the subsequent call to the function.

---

Do note that this answer uses a different approach to avoid [*busy-waiting*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), which *may* be undesirable.

Comment: Correct! This actually calls the function with 1 second _delays_ instead. Edited for clarification!